# java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010026: Async is not supported for this request, as not all filters or Servlets were marked as supporting async

Tags: jsf, primefaces, push, atmosphere

Push is not working for me in PrimeFaces 5.3 :

web.xml.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
    <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0-RC5</version>
</dependency>
```

I´m using WildFly 8.2

I got this:

```
ERROR [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-61) AtmosphereFramework exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010026: Async is not supported for this request, as not all filters or Servlets were marked as supporting async
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You don't have any filters in web.xml?

Comment: sure. For example
<filter>
  <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>de.dpunkt.myaktion.util.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>ignore</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
   <description>the encoding to use</description>
   <param-name>encoding</param-name>

 </filter>

  <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>

Comment: Could you try putting <async-supported>true</async-supported> on all those filters

Comment: Thank you it works, but I got now this exception: [org.atmosphere.container.JSR356Endpoint] (default task-2) : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Reason Phrase cannot exceed 123 UTF-8 encoded bytes: No SecurityManager accessible to the calling code, either bound to the org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext or as a vm static singleton.  This is an invalid application configuration.

Comment: New questions in new topics please

Answer (score 0):

```
// servlet.setAsyncSupported(true);

//For Example

public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(WebMvcConfig.class);
        ctx.register(WebHibernateConfiguration.class);
        ctx.register(SwaggerConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher",
            new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setAsyncSupported(true); //Servlets were marked as supporting async
        // For CORS Pre Filght Request
        servlet.setInitParameter("dispatchOptionsRequest", "true");
    }
}
```

Comment: servlet.setAsyncSupported(true);

Comment: Please add some text explanation to your answer